# CABasicAnimation is not animating. Help?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, core-animation, layer

Now before you get all antsy, this is ***Cocoa*** I'm talking about, not *Cocoa-Touch*. With that out of the way, lets begin.  I have recently started programming for the Mac.  Why?  Because it's cool.  You know what's not cool?  Not being able to have nice fancy animations like the other cool kids.  I can't figure this out and if you can help me you will save the few hairs I have left on my head.

Alright, I have a `NSCollectionView`.  Took me ages to figure that out, but whatever.  I've made that `NSCollectionView` layer-backed in Interface Builder.  I heard that's supposed to make this magic work.  I tried this to animate my collection view:

```
//usersView is my NSCollectionView
CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];    
CATransform3D scale = CATransform3DMakeScale(2.0, 2.0, 0.0);
[anim setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DIdentity]];
[anim setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:scale]];
[anim setDuration:1.0f];
[[usersView layer] addAnimation:anim forKey:nil];
[[usersView layer] setTransform:scale];
```

Now here's the deal: it *does* transform the view, but not with a cool animation.  I also tried this:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];
[CATransaction setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:3.0f] forKey:kCATransactionAnimationDuration];
[usersView layer].transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(2.0, 2.0, 0.0);
[CATransaction commit];
```

No dice.  I do believe I need help.  Thanks.

Comment: Is the `NSCollectionView`'s superview also layer-backed?

Comment: @Rob: By superview, do you mean the view that contains the `NSCollectionView`?  No it's not.  The reason why is because it's a transparent window and I don't want the view to be the ugly greyish color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that for your second piece of code that attempts an implied animation (by assigning a new value for the `transform` property) you need to skip setting the `kCATransactionDisableActions` property to `true` since in effect that says **not to animate** the transition (which is exactly the opposite of your intention).  To be explicit you could set that property to `false.`  There could easily be some other issue at play too; I never seem to know exactly what's needed until it's coded and running. (With core animation I always find myself inching towards the result I want bit by bit.  But after finally getting *at least something* to animate it really inspires me to continue tweaking the code till it works the way I want it!, i.e., core animation isn't an easy one to pick up.)

As for the first problem, the explicit animation, I believe one problem has to do with the last line where you set the layer's transform property; I'd start by leaving that out (though it may have to be worked back in someplace else in the long run).  Setting that transform immediately changes the layer to how it should look when the animation is complete  (which is why you see the transformation occur immediately) but that doesn't completely explain not seeing any animation since the transaction (which begins once your code is complete, i.e., after the immediate transition has occurred) does have both a 'start' and an 'end' value.  To start, I'd begin by finding some example code that does a similar animation and changing it piece by piece to get what you want. (That's how I learned to use core animation after trying to completely code an animation by myself and having it fail; it did take a long time to get it right but I really got a better feeling for it in doing so.)  You might also want to go back to the documentation and really try to get the concept of the `core animation rendering architecture`, i.e., the *layer-tree,* the *presentation-tree* and the *render-tree* and what is displayed at different stages of the animation as well as how to affect it (which again will really only sink in after a bunch of trial and error).  Just stick with it till it makes sense!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write all that out.  Great information.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use

```
[usersView setWantsLayer:YES];
```

if you figure out that your layer is nil. By default all views don't have layers.

Answer (score 0):

After a few tries, I finally got my animations to work. There are a few things to watch our for.

**If you want the transform to be anchored in the center, then you should call `anchorPoint` on `CALayer:` *before* adding the view to its superview! Otherwise the subview will be cropped off starting at the `anchorPoint` location.**

```
CALayer *layer = _completionIndicator.layer;
layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(.5, .5);
```

**Wrap the animation calls in a `runAnimationGroup` block (`_completionIndicator` is a property defined as an `NSView`, and `centerInSuperview` is defined below):**

```
[self.contentView addSubview:_completionIndicator];
[_completionIndicator centerInSuperview];

[NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext *context) {
    CGFloat duration = <#duration#>;

    CALayer *layer = _completionIndicator.layer;
    CABasicAnimation *animation;

    //Transform
    animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
    animation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(<#scale#>, <#scale#>, 1.0)];
    animation.toValue =   [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DIdentity];
    [animation setDuration:duration];
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    [layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"zoomIn"];

    //Fade
    animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
    animation.toValue =   [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
    [animation setDuration:duration];
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    [layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"fadeIn"];
} completionHandler:^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:<#seconds#>];
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self hideCompletionIndicator];
        });

    });

}];
```

**Setting the `fillMode` was essential for a smooth animation. The default is `kCAFillModeRemoved`, which causes jumps when running the animation after the first run.**

On OSX 10.11, setting `wantsLayer` on the `NSView` is not necessary. I don't know about previous versions.

**To hide the view, simply do the opposite, and remove the view in the completion block:**

```
- (void) hideCompletionIndicator
{
    [NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext *context) {
        CGFloat duration = <#duration#>;

        CALayer *layer = _completionIndicator.layer;
        CABasicAnimation *animation;

        //Transform
        animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
        animation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DIdentity];
        animation.toValue =   [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(<#scale#>, <#scale#>, 1.0)];
        [animation setDuration:duration];
        animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
        animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
        [layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"zoomOut"];

        //Fade
        animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
        animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
        animation.toValue =   [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
        [animation setDuration:duration];
        animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
        animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
        [layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"fadeOut"];
    } completionHandler:^{
        [_completionIndicator removeFromSuperview];
    }];
}
```

**NSView category implementation**

```
@implementation NSView (Additions)

- (void) centerInSuperview
{
    [self centerInView:[self superview]];
}

- (void) centerInView:(NSView *)otherView
{
    int w = self.frame.size.width;
    int h = self.frame.size.height;
    int x = (otherView.frame.size.width - w)/2;
    int y = (otherView.frame.size.height - h)/2;

    self.frame = NSMakeRect(x, y, w, h);

}

@end
```

**NSView category interface**

```
@interface NSView (Additions)

- (void) centerInSuperview;
- (void) centerInView:(NSView *)otherView;

@end
```